# How to prevent chrome debugger from stepping into empty files in javascript

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, google-chrome-devtools

When I put a breakpoint on some code written which uses external libraries, Chrome debugger seems to step into blank pages and I get lost and can't debug further because of that. Is there some way to prevent Chrome from getting into these blank pages (which seem to be files of the external libraries) which stepping through?

Answer (score 0):

You may use blackboxing to skip the libraries code.

For more information see the Google article :
[Blackbox JavaScript Source Files](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing).

> Blackboxing gives you a first-class way to denote library (or other abstraction) code so that the debugger can route around it. When you blackbox a source file, the debugger will not jump into that file when stepping through code you're debugging.

You may use regular expressions for the source file to skip, for skipping
more than one file with one rule.